# filepermisson problems using ZipArchive in php

Tags: php, permissions, zip, extract

i have to extract some zip files, the zip extraction works... but i don't have write permission on the extracted files.

```
$res = $zip->open($this->importDirectory . 'archive.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
$zip->extractTo($this->importDirectory . 'somefolder/');
$zip->close(); 
}
```

somebody help me please :D

Answer (score 2):

try to use the Php chmod function before to open the file ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php )

```
chmod($this->importDirectory . 'archive.zip', 755);
```

Hope this useful

Answer (score 1):

Your script isn't running with your permissions, so files owned by user running the script/web-server/cgi-worker/etc...

You may use [`chmod`](http://php.net/chmod) to change permissions for extracted files or [`chown`](http://php.net/chown) to change ownership (if it's allowed for user who run the script).